# Theoretically maximum correlation coefficient between multiple correlated variables

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

Say I have an observable *z*, which linearly correlated with two other variables *x* and *y*, like this:

```
z = ax + by
```

If you  assume *x* and *y* are completely uncorrelated, I would think that the correlation coefficient *Rx,z* or *Ry,z* can not become one (or even close to). Is there a theoretical maximum for this correlation coefficient? And if yes, how can you prove it? And what is it? I'm guessing it would depend on *a* and *b*.

Comment: Consider $a = 0$.  What's the correlation between $z$ and $y$?

Comment: Well, assuming b is not zero it would be one. But I'm more interested in the non-trivial cases.

Comment: $a=0$ isn't "trivial." If you want to exclude it, what would your answer be for $a=10^{-100}$? If you fix $a$ and $b$, then you're asking how to compute the correlation of $z$ in terms of the variances and covariances of $x$ and $y$--which is a standard formula you can readily find in many threads here.